# Class Id from view to other class/view MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

So i'm working with MVC 4 and i have a question. I have two classes, Schedule and Simulation(its to simulate a student to enter the classroom). I have a view that gives all the schedules that exists next to a link to simulate entrance (it's another view, another class). I would like to pass the id from the schedule that the person chooses to a attribute in the Simulation class.

Class simulation:

```
    namespace GestorSalas.Models
{
    public class Simulation
    {
        public virtual int SimulationId { get; set; }
        public virtual int ScheduleId { get; set; }

        public virtual string Utilizador { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Tipo de Utilizador")]
        public virtual string TipoUtilizador { get; set; }

        public virtual int Codigo { get; set; }

        public virtual string Hora { get; set; }

        public virtual bool Entrar { get; set; }

    }
```

Class Schedule:

```
    namespace GestorSalas.Models
{
    public class Schedule
    {
        public virtual int ScheduleId { get; set; }
        public virtual int DisciplinaId { get; set; }
        public virtual int SalaId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual int Dia { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Hora de Entrada")]
        public virtual string HoraEntrada { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Hora de Saida")]
        public virtual string HoraSaida { get; set; }

        public virtual Disciplina Disciplina { get; set; }
        public virtual Sala Sala { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the view: (what the user sees)
[image]

(Entrar na sala=link to the simulation create view, in this image is the schedule index view).
I would like to pass the id from the schedule in order to appear in the simulation form (or in the table after the creation, much like when we click details or edit and it takes the user id but i want the schedule id).
This is the code in the "Entrar em sala" link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Entrar em sala", "Create", "Simulation", new {id = item.HorarioId }, null)
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas on how can i do this?

**EDIT:** The controllers:

Simulation:
To create
    //
            // GET: /Simulacao/Create

```
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Simulacao/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(Simulation simulation)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Simulacaos.Add(simulation);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(simulation);
        }
```

And the schedule is just the index that is being used here:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var schedules= db.Schedules.Include(h => h.Disciplina).Include(h => h.Sala);
            return View(schedules.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: can you post your controller?

Comment: sure, i will edit the post

Answer (score 1):

Your create method should accept the `id` as a parameter and use it as needed.

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
  // Id has the scheduleId
  // to do  : Do something with the Id passed in and return something

}
```

and in your index view, you need to pass the `scheduleId` as value of route param `Id`

```
@model List<Schedule>
<h2>Simulator</h2>
<table>
 <tr><th>HoraEntrada </th><th>Dia </th><th></th></tr>
 @foreach(var item in Model)
 {
   <tr>
    <td>@item.HoraSaida</td>
    <td>@item.Dia</td>
    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Entrar em sala", "Create", "Simulation",
                                                        new {@id = item.ScheduleId}, null)
     </td>
   </tr>           
 }
</table>
```

Comment: well it gives the id already, but now it shows this error "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'GestorSalas.Models.Schedule'."

Comment: @abcdef, That is an entirely different issue and the message is self explanatory - you need to pass an instance of your model to the view in the `Create(int ID)` method - e.g. `return View(new Simulation());`